# Obtain generic entries with ChangeTacker

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity base clas:

```
public class Entity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; private set; }

    private List<INotification> _domainEvents;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<INotification> DomainEvents => _domainEvents;

    …
}
```

My entities can have different types of Id: Entity< Guid>, Entity< int>, etc.

The problem is I need to the domain entities with ChangeTracker:

```
var domainEntities = context.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Entity<TSomeType>>()
    .Where(x => x.Entity.DomainEvents != null && x.Entity.DomainEvents.Any());
```

Without a generic base class, I just put "Entity" and works, but I have a generic and I don't know the possible types of TSomeType. How can I obtain the entries?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work 100%, depends on your implementation, but maybe try adding a generic type with constraints on the method (or class) this code is in, like:

`void SomeMethod<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity<TKey>`

and then using this generic type in your code:

`var domainEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Entity.DomainEvents != null && x.Entity.DomainEvents.Any());
`

Answer (score 1):

Add a common interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<INotification> DomainEvents { get; }
}

public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity
{
    public TKey Id { get; private set; }

    private List<INotification> _domainEvents;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<INotification> DomainEvents => _domainEvents;

    …
}
```

Once you do that you can access DomainEvents via the interface, e.g.

```
var domainEntities = context.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Entity<TSomeType>>()
    .Cast<IEntity>()
    .Where(x => x.DomainEvents != null && x.DomainEvents.Any());
```

Comment: .Entries<Entity<TSomeType>>()? I don't know what types are TSomeType

Comment: It's from your example. Whatever type you want.

Comment: It's an example trying to use a generic entity. I don't know what TSomeTypes will use the client.

Comment: It doesn't matter. That is the point of the interface. Wasn't that the question?

Comment: It should be `context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>()`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some of you is using also AggregateRoot as an abstract class going hand-in-hand with Entity. I've provided a solution which handles this problem but also extends the generic repository pattern.

It is maybe an overkill for what the author's original question was, but it handles also Identity since the author is probably going to use this in DDD.

```cs
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        ...
    }

    public abstract class Entity<TId> : Entity where TId : Identity
    {      
        ...
    }
```

```
    public interface IAggregateRoot
    {
        IReadOnlyList<IDomainEvent> DomainEvents { get; }
        void ClearEvents();
    }

    // Note: Here the 'IAggregateRoot' needs to be inbetween 'Entity<TId>' & 'where TId'
    public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId> : Entity<TId>, IAggregateRoot where TId : Identity
    {
        private readonly List<IDomainEvent> _domainEvents = new List<IDomainEvent>();
        public virtual IReadOnlyList<IDomainEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();

        protected virtual void AddDomainEvent(IDomainEvent newEvent)
        {
            _domainEvents.Add(newEvent);
        }

        public virtual void ClearEvents()
        {
            _domainEvents.Clear();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class OrderId : Identity
    {
         ...
    }

    public interface IRepository<T, TId> where T : AggregateRoot<TId>
                                         where TId: Identity
    {
        T Add(T entity);
        ...
    }

    public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order, OrderId>
    {
       ...
    }
```

And you use the IAggregateRoot at the ChangeTracker

```
var domainEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAggregateRoot>()
               .Select(x => x.Entity)
               .Where(x => x.DomainEvents.Any())
               .ToList();
```